# Flutter with Firebase Google sign in: Failed assertion network_image_io.dart

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-signin

I'm trying to do Firebase authentication and Google sign in using Flutter but I'm getting this error message:

```
'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 23 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.
```

I can't understand what is wrong, can you help me?

**login.dart code snippet**

-> calls signInWithGoogle() method from sign_in.dart and return FirstScreen

```
Widget _signInButton() {
    return OutlineButton(
      splashColor: Colors.grey,
      onPressed: () {
        signInWithGoogle().whenComplete(() {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) {
                return FirstScreen();
              },
            ),
          );
        });
      },
```

**sign_in.dart code snippet:**

-> Here I authenticate the user and try to get logged user name, email and image

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

String name;
String email;
String imageUrl;

Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
  await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
    idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
  );

  final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  final FirebaseUser user = authResult.user;

  // Checking if email and name is null
  assert(user.email != null);
  assert(user.displayName != null);
  assert(user.photoUrl != null);

  name = user.displayName;
  email = user.email;
  imageUrl = user.photoUrl;

  // Only taking the first part of the name, i.e., First Name
  if (name.contains(" ")) {
    name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(" "));
  }

  assert(!user.isAnonymous);
  assert(await user.getIdToken() != null);

  final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

  log('data:  $user');
  return 'signInWithGoogle succeeded: $user';
}

void signOutGoogle() async {
  await googleSignIn.signOut();

  print("User Sign Out");
}
```

**FirstScreen code snippet:**

-> Here I try to show user data (name, email and image) based on what I got on previously code

```
children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                  imageUrl,
                ),
                radius: 60,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 40),
              Text(
                'NAME',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black54),
              ),
              Text(
                name,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20),
              Text(
                'EMAIL',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.black54),
              ),
              Text(
                email,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 40)
```

EDIT: aditional info -> console log shows "Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null)"

Comment: Have you added your android debugkey SHA-1 fingerprints in your firebase console and updated google-services.json file after adding them?

Comment: Yes, I did and still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a day to find my way around the Google SignIn package with various fixes and troubleshooting, I realised there is web package Google has made for web sign in which uses the OAuthClient verification and configuration as per their changing policy with Google Sign in.

Sadly it isn't straight forward and quick as it was before. But following the steps mentioned in the pub.dev.

https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in_web

Attaching my main.dart working POC snippets here.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert' show json;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  // Optional clientId
  // clientId: '479882132969-9i9aqik3jfjd7qhci1nqf0bm2g71rm1u.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  scopes: <String>[
    'email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  ],
);

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Sign In',
      home: SignInDemo(),
    ),
  );
}

class SignInDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInDemo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => SignInDemoState();
}

class SignInDemoState extends State<SignInDemo> {
  GoogleSignInAccount? _currentUser;
  String _contactText = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) {
      setState(() {
        _currentUser = account;
      });
      if (_currentUser != null) {
        _handleGetContact(_currentUser!);
      }
    });
    _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
  }

  Future<void> _handleGetContact(GoogleSignInAccount user) async {
    setState(() {
      _contactText = 'Loading contact info...';
    });
    final http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections'
          '?requestMask.includeField=person.names'),
      headers: await user.authHeaders,
    );
    if (response.statusCode != 200) {
      setState(() {
        _contactText = 'People API gave a ${response.statusCode} '
            'response. Check logs for details.';
      });
      print('People API ${response.statusCode} response: ${response.body}');
      return;
    }
    final Map<String, dynamic> data =
    json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    final String? namedContact = _pickFirstNamedContact(data);
    setState(() {
      if (namedContact != null) {
        _contactText = 'I see you know $namedContact!';
      } else {
        _contactText = 'No contacts to display.';
      }
    });
  }

  String? _pickFirstNamedContact(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    final List<dynamic>? connections = data['connections'] as List<dynamic>?;
    final Map<String, dynamic>? contact = connections?.firstWhere(
          (dynamic contact) => (contact as Map<Object?, dynamic>)['names'] != null,
      orElse: () => null,
    ) as Map<String, dynamic>?;
    if (contact != null) {
      final List<dynamic> names = contact['names'] as List<dynamic>;
      final Map<String, dynamic>? name = names.firstWhere(
            (dynamic name) =>
        (name as Map<Object?, dynamic>)['displayName'] != null,
        orElse: () => null,
      ) as Map<String, dynamic>?;
      if (name != null) {
        return name['displayName'] as String?;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignOut() => _googleSignIn.disconnect();

  Widget _buildBody() {
    final GoogleSignInAccount? user = _currentUser;
    if (user != null) {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            leading: GoogleUserCircleAvatar(
              identity: user,
            ),
            title: Text(user.displayName ?? ''),
            subtitle: Text(user.email),
          ),
          const Text('Signed in successfully.'),
          Text(_contactText),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _handleSignOut,
            child: const Text('SIGN OUT'),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('REFRESH'),
            onPressed: () => _handleGetContact(user),
          ),
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: <Widget>[
          const Text('You are not currently signed in.'),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: _handleSignIn,
            child: const Text('SIGN IN'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Google Sign In'),
        ),
        body: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(),
          child: _buildBody(),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found that the error I was getting was due to the lack of some OAuth Credentials settings. I found the solution [here](https://blog.codemagic.io/firebase-authentication-google-sign-in-using-flutter/)